# Embedding python: Version inconsistent with ProgramFullPath

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, embedding, python-embedding

I have anaconda Python first on my path, but a simple Python embedding example shows my Mac system python version instead, even though `ProgramFullPath` correctly points to anaconda python. Is there a way to correctly find / use anaconda python?

Minimal example:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    Py_Initialize();
    printf("Python version:\n%s\n", Py_GetVersion());
    printf("Python Program Full Path:\n%s\n", Py_GetProgramFullPath());
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with,

```
gcc `python-config --cflags` example.c `python-config --ldflags`
```

or, expanding the results of the `python-config` calls,

```
gcc -I/Users/ryandwyer/anaconda/include/python2.7 \
    -I/Users/ryandwyer/anaconda/include/python2.7 \
    -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/ryandwyer/anaconda/include \
    -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes \
    example.c -lpython2.7 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -u _PyMac_Error
```

Running the program gives,

```
Python version:
2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]
Python Program Full Path:
/Users/ryandwyer/anaconda/bin/python
```

This seems to be the same problem as [Embed python in c++: choose python version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25571870/2823213). I have also tried setting `PYTHONHOME`, `Py_SetProgramName`, `Py_SetPythonHome`, but cannot get `Python_GetVersion()` to return the anaconda version.

Answer (score 1):

There was a partial answer in the post you linked.

**Option 1:** Run your program as follows

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_to_anaconda/lib ./program

**Option 2:** Run the following command in the terminal, then run your program

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_to_anaconda/lib
 ./program

**Option 3:** Add the following line to the end of your .bashrc file

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path_to_anaconda/lib

Why do you have to do this when embedding python, but not when running the interpreter normally? I have no idea, but if some Python/C wizard stumbles on this post I'd love to know why.